# Solr can I clear down slave/replica to pull in all the data from master again

Tags: solr

We had a situation where a slave was misconfigured in its **managed-schema** file. This now has 700,000+ documents in the slave, but we didn't have the two index fields defined in the managed-schema on this instance. We did have it right on the master and on another slave.

What would be the way to clear down the slave and let it pull in all the data again?

- Delete the data folder?
- Delete the core outright from the slave and recreate linking it to the master.
- Or is it a simple as clearing the slave core with the following? it seems that it will get back in sync just by doing this!?
  [image: List item]

Just wondering if there is a quick way of clearing the data and resetting the version?